# java WordGame program

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am totally a beginner. This is a project for school. I just need to know, can anyone tell me why this won't run ?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class WordGame
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String name;
      name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");

      String age;
      age= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your age");

      String city;
      city= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of a city");

      String college;
      college= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of a college");

      String profession;
      profession= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter profession");

      String animal;
      animal= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a type of animal");

      String pet;
      pet= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a pet name");

      String str="There once was a person named "+ name+
      " \n who lived in CITY. At the age of "+age+
      ", "+ name +" went to college at \n"+ college+" ."+ name
      +" graduated and went to work as a \n"+profession+" . Then, "+ name
      +" adopted a(n) "+ animal +" \n named "+ pet+
      ". They both lived happily ever after!";
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. What doesn't work? Why? What's happening? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: What errors or odd behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: this is the error I get.  Compilation error time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0

Main.java:2: error: class WordGame is public, should be declared in a file named WordGame.java
public class WordGame

Comment: I'm using ideone.com to test it. I don't know if that's part of the problem.

Comment: @user2302865 I would say yes, that is the problem. It can't seem to allocate memory. Furthermore it can't save the file.

Comment: what should I do differently ?

Comment: @user2302865 Try using `class WordGame` instead of `public class WordGame` (remove the `public` keyword)

Comment: @BackSlash that will not work

Comment: @VD' Since the OP is trying to compile on IDEOne, it will work. Ideone says *You can give the class whatever name you want, but if it's public you* ***must name it Main***

Answer (score 0):

considering you have JRE/JDK installed on your system

create a file named "`WordGame.java`" put it in a directory say `D:/Test`

now go to command prompt and run `javac WordGame.java` this will compile the code and generate a class file

now run `SET CLASS_PATH=.` to temporary setting current directory as classpath

and then run `java WordGame` and there you go.. you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program on my computer and it ran just fine. The only problem with your code is where it says:

```
 String str="There once was a person named "+ name+
      " \n who lived in CITY. At the age of "+age+
      ", "+ name +" went to college at \n"+ college+" ."+ name
      +" graduated and went to work as a \n"+profession+" . Then, "+ name
      +" adopted a(n) "+ animal +" \n named "+ pet+
      ". They both lived happily ever after!";
```

Instead of saying CITY, you should output the city name entered by the user. Otherwise, your code works correctly! :)